# How do you read xml data from a project resource into a dataset?

Tags: xml, dataset

I have an xml file that is a project resource. I can access it via Properties.Resources.DrivereSettings. The xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FilterOffsets>
  <FocusOffset>
    <SerialNumber>12543</SerialNumber>
    <Filter>4</Filter>
    <Wheel>A</Wheel>
    <Offset>7</Offset>
  </FocusOffset>
</FilterOffsets>
```

I want to load this data into the dataset of an xmlDataDocument. If I use this code, `xmlDataDoc.LoadXml(Properties.Resources.DriverSettings);` The data does not get loaded into the dataset. There are 0 tables. Is that because my xml is formatted incorrectly? How can I get the data into the dataset and then make changes to the dataset and write them back to the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to first read the resource into a `String`, and then use loadXml from that `String`.

Answer (score 0):

put your xml text in StringReader like below

System.IO.StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader(xmltext);

ds.ReadXml(sr);